# Differential equation solution solving in net or software

Tags: calculus, integration, ordinary-differential-equations, discrete-mathematics

I want to calculate long differential equation very quickly without doing calculations. Is there any way to solve Ordinary differential equation in online or in a software?

Comment: You mean, symbolically? You could use Maple or Mathematica.

Comment: Write your differential equation in Wolfram Alpha.

Comment: I want to avoid long equations, and quick solutions.

Answer (score 2):

You might want to look into a [*Computer Algebra System*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_computer_algebra_systems) and there are commercial and open source variants.

Examples are Mathematica (Wolfram Alpha uses this as the backend), Maple, Matlab...
Some of these also include home and student versions for cheaper.

Open source examples are Maxima, SAGE, Axiom, ... Some of these even have online versions, but those might not be fully functional.

Regards

Comment: All good suggestions! +1